# Is there a way to insert a list into the .format method in python?

Tags: python, list, printing, string.format

I want to do something like:

```
list = [1,2,3]
valstring = "one: {}, two: {}, three: {}".format(list)
print(valstring)
```

result:

```
one: 1, two: 2, three: 3
```

Is something like this possible? I know I can achieve a similar result by using `.format(list[0], list[1], list[2])` but I have a long list so I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Is the word coming from the index, or the value of the number it's paired with?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use asterisk `*` (so called "*unpacking*" in Python):

```
lst = [1,2,3]
valstring = "one: {}, two: {}, three: {}".format(*lst)
print(valstring)
```

Prints:

```
one: 1, two: 2, three: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate these strings for arbitrarily long inputs, you can use the [`inflect`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect) package to get the English words for integers.

```
import inflect 

eng = inflect.engine()

l = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
pairs = ['{}: {}'.format(eng.number_to_words(index), value) for index, value in enumerate(l, start=1)]
print(', '.join(pairs))
# one: 5, two: 4, three: 3, four: 2, five: 1
```